# Simple SQL Server Delete fails

Tags: sql-server

I am seeing intermittent failures upon a simple delete.

Essentially I have a temporary note that has many entries. Each entry has a classification which is a lookup value. Once this note is completed, it gets sent to a note repository, and the temporary version needs to be deleted.

I can't replicate reliably, but on occasion, when calling the stored procedure that does the delete of the temp note, only SOME of the entries get deleted. Coincidentally (?) the entry left behind has always been of one specific classification type.

After many many many attempts I was able to reproduce the issue while running SQL Server Profiler. Despite trying to catch Attention, ErrorLog, EventLog, Exception, and Execution Warnings, the resulting profile shows nothing out of the ordinary.

None of the involved tables are large. In fact they're minuscule. ~100-1000 at any given time in Entry, ~100 in Draft, 9 in Classification, 3 in Category.

I don't believe it should matter, but just in case, this stored procedure is being called from Entity Framework.

Any ideas? Any ideas on what to try for troubleshooting? I'm completely at a loss. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the stored procedure for deletion:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [NoteDraft].[ClearNoteDraft]
    @DraftId BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM NoteDraft.[Entry]
    WHERE DraftId = @DraftId

    DELETE FROM NoteDraft.Draft
    WHERE Id = @DraftId
END
```

Here are the table definitions (with some columns left out for brevity as noted.)

```
CREATE TABLE [NoteDraft].[Category]
(
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [SortOrder] [int] NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Category] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [NoteDraft].[Classification]
(
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [SortOrder] [int] NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Classification] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [NoteDraft].[Draft]
(
   [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [DateModified] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TestNoteDraft_DateModified]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
   [AccountNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
   --...10 other biz columns...
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Notes] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [NoteDraft].[Entry]
(
   [DraftId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [ClassificationId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Body] [varchar](2100) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Entry] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DraftId] ASC, [ClassificationId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [NoteDraft].[Classification] WITH CHECK 
     ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Classification_Category] 
         FOREIGN KEY([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [NoteDraft].[Category] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [NoteDraft].[Classification] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Classification_Category]
GO

ALTER TABLE [NoteDraft].[Entry]  WITH CHECK 
     ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Entry_Classification] 
         FOREIGN KEY([ClassificationId]) REFERENCES [NoteDraft].[Classification] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [NoteDraft].[Entry] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Entry_Classification]
GO

ALTER TABLE [NoteDraft].[Entry]  WITH CHECK 
     ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Entry_Draft] 
         FOREIGN KEY([DraftId]) REFERENCES [NoteDraft].[Draft] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [NoteDraft].[Entry] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Entry_Draft]
GO
```

Comment: By default EF does not wrap queries in a transaction, you might look at that and isolation levels -- [SQL Server Isolation Levels: A Series - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/t-sql-queries/isolation-levels)

Comment: Are you certain the Entry record exists before you delete it? If the intention is to move the record to a different table, you should really include the INSERT and DELETE in a single transaction (it would make sense to put it into this stored procedure).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am certain that the records exist, as they are displayed on the site, and during troubleshooting I've been hitting the table after each step to watch it change.. The repository is actually a completely different system submitted via web service from inside the website, but the thought is a good one. I'll try wrapping it in a transaction and see if I can make it fail again.

Answer (score 0):

As with everything simple like this, the answer wasn't where I was looking.

Turns out, there's an event listener on the page that's re-inserting the records post deletion.

Still having trouble figuring out why the listener is running, but at least I know what's going on.